# Default Subscribers for Filed Against in RTC

Tags: rtc

Is there a way in RTC to setup default subscribers for filled against?

In our workflow we have a design team, a UI team, a QA team, etc. When we change work items in RTC to be filled against those guys (or when we create new work items), we want people in those teams to be getting emails from RTC...

I think it might have something to do with customizing the attributes described in here:
https://jazz.net/library/article/537

but I don't think this describes exactly what I want to do...

This article here: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21580771

Talks about adding default subscribers to all work items overall, which is close to what I want but not quite...

Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Note: "filed against" means category (which can be associated to team area), not subscriber.

Comment: Ok, is there any way to have default subscribers in team areas then? I think our team is used to bugzilla where when people filed bugs against certain teams the entire team would just get pinged about it...